# Replacing a base assembly with source code in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Suppose you have an assembly `B` that references `A` and you have the source code for the assembly `A` only. Is it possible to build from source code the assembly A and debug it?

Currently we get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'name' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference.

Is there any way to bypass it?

Comment: build A and put breakpoints should work.

Comment: Add the project for assembly A to your solution, and then change the reference in assembly B to refer to the assembly A project. You can then directly debug assembly A.

Comment: According to your description, you want to solve the assembly reference problem.
I suggest that Right-click the project to view the reference properties, determine whether the reference path is correct, and delete the referenced dll file and re-reference the dll file in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on if the original assembly A that is referenced is [strongly named](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/strong-named). This is a feature where assemblies are signed. Keys for all compile time references are stored in the built assembly, B in your case. When loading assemblies the loader may then verify the signatures of all references to ensure the correct assembly is loaded.

So if strong naming is used it is not easy to replace the assembly A with a newer version without recompiling B. There is however a [strong name validation bypass feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/create-use-strong-named) for full trust application domains.

If you manage to bypass or disable the strong naming you should simply be able to replace the file in the directory with the new version and attach visual studio.

Comment: After adding the `AllowStrongNameBypass` DWORD key to the machine registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework` nothing has changed. Is there anything else we shoud try? Thanks.